# DPDT >30 Amp Latching relay

Tags: power, latching-relay

I currently use a DPDT 30 Amp relay to switch between a utility supplied 120 VAC and an inverter supplied 120 VAC. The relay has a 120 VAC coil. I use the inverter 120 VAC power source to energize the relay coil. So whenever the inverter is turned on, it energizes the relay and switches the supply power from utility to the inverter. The problem is, the efficiency of the inverter supplied power is diminished by the amount of current it takes to hold the energizing coil. So, if I could latch that energizing coil to the on position until the inverter is turned off, I could increase the efficiency of this switch. I am concerned about the failure mode though. The failure mode of a solid state solution to this is why I haven't pursued that route. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What is the holding current of the relay?

Comment: Is utility power limited such that utility power could not hold the relay?

Comment: If you want an automatic transfer switch you should probably buy one.

Answer (score 2):

> *I currently use a DPDT 30 Amp relay to switch between a utility
>   supplied 120 VAC and an inverter supplied 120 VAC.*

And...

> *Does anyone have a solution?*

It's a double throw relay (DPDT) so energize the coil from the incoming AC (from the mains) and rewire the relay contacts accordingly so that when the relay is inactivated (no AC power), the inverter output is connected to the load.

Comment: Correct, OP is doing it upside down and backwards.  Utility power should be treated as the abundant resource.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, with a standard DPDT relay energised by the utility supply but de-energised by the inverter through a low coil consumption relay.

[image]

Comment: The OP's mains is always on. This will never switch to inverter.

Comment: Hi Transistor, Many thanks for drawing attention to the Op's prime requirement of the inverter being in command. That changeover to inverter should happen only when the utility is down, is a typical mindset. This could be a case of changeover to solar power when available. My post requires editing.

Comment: It's been done!

Comment: Maybe, I should try to clarify this operation. To Michael Harvey, the holding current to the coil is .5 Amp. To  Harper - Reinstate Monica, it was never my intention to use the utility power to operate the relay, but to minimize the use of utility power altogether. If my batteries would hold up, my inverter would operate my loads all of the time.

Comment: It works beautifully. I'm only trying to minimize coil holding current or eliminate it altogether. To vu2nan, This is what I’ve been looking for, but can’t seem to find. I've been looking for a Latching relay, but a Low Holding current coil would do the trick.

Comment: @sdingman, Thank you for the information.  A 120V~ relay with 1.2 VA coil would be standard with most of the manufacturers. You would also need a relay base with screw terminals for easy wiring.

Comment: vu2nan, Thanks for your comment. I'm currently using https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00SFYWO02/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1. It does have screw terminals. Please refer me to the Low Holding current Coil that you discussed. Thanks

Comment: sdingman, Here's one. https://gfinder.findernet.com/public/attachments/46/EN/S46EN.pdf

Comment: sdingman, One more. https://www.grainger.com/product/SCHNEIDER-ELECTRIC-120VAC-Coil-Volts-6CWE9

Comment: @vu2nan, Thanks for the references. The schematic that you provided on the earlier post is exactly what I have, but with a minor difference. The small relay that completes the circuit to provide the 120 vac to the larger 30 Amp relay coil, is operated by a 5 vdc signal from a micro-controller. Its holding current is not the issue that I'm trying address. It's the current through the contacts of the small relay to hold the 30 Amp DPDT  relay coil energized, that I'm trying to minimize. That current is .5 Amp. I'm looking for the 30 Amp DPDT relay to be a Latching type relay.

Comment: Hi sdingman, The problem with a latching relay would be non-availability of power to unlatch it at inverter turn-off.

Comment: Hi sdingman, The problem with a latching relay in your scheme would be non-availability of power to unlatch it when the inverter shuts down. According to my schematic, shown above, the 30A DPDT relay is turned off when the inverter is on and cannot be a drain on it. With the inverter off, the 30A DPDT relay is energised by the utility supply to power the load. When utility power is not available the load would switch back to the inverter.

Comment: Hi sdingman, With the load on utility power, the 30A DPDT relay coil would also be a part of the load.